# Handling audio signals on a 5v ADC

Tags: arduino, operational-amplifier, audio

Some days ago I have made a multiplexed 3x8 LED grid based on [Arduino RGB Controller](http://blog.tkjelectronics.dk/2011/08/arduino-rgb-led-controller/). In my case I don't use RGB but row1, row2 and row3. While I already made some nice animations but I'm not  really happy with the result. The matrix is 1m x 2,8m, I'm planing to append it over some sort of "home music studio". As you know visualizing audio stuff is cool! So the static animations on that LED matrix would be useless if not following the beat. I need to add a spectrum analyer. Luckly all the analog I/O are free to use.
Another point that makes this grid perfect for a 8 channel spectrum analyzer is the fact that I'm allowed to use PWM on the 3 rows. This means I have a theoretical spectrum grid of 256*3 x 8. Naturally the curve from 0-100% of the LED's brighness is not linear, that can be solved by using a simeple exponential function. Anyway the animation should be nicer than just fully turning on/off the LEDs.

First of all let me tell you again, I'm not an electronical enginer and I doing my best to understand stuff by myself, but in this case I'm not able to do it properly. My only measuring system is a very slow limited multimeter. I also broke an arduino some months ago, so I don't just connect stuff.

**Can the arduino create a spectrum analyzer using only one pin?**

yes! [FHT](http://wiki.openmusiclabs.com/wiki/ArduinoFHT)

And so I started to read about that

1. I need to somehow convert the audio signal to 0-5V
2. I need to read the data on the ADC0 (left audio channel) and do some math and send it to the LEDs.

I'm stuck at point 1.

Every Audio device headphones output's max defer so I need a potentiometer.
The audio voltage is low milliamps but also most of the time lower voltage.

From the various circuits I choosed the following one. Before I connected it to the arduino I used a buzzer to test if I get something out. Yes but, I get sound if I invert GND with signal(Jack in) and I also get sound if I invert the polarity of the capacitor C1.
There is also no type of protection in this circuit, I am stucked.

Note.: I also tested differnt other circuits and got alwasy the same results, except in this the potentiometer has no effect.

[image]

**Result:**

> With a simple analog read I always get 0(ZERO).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNAwC3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Reading more about the problem I found many posts that use op-amps.
Since my local electronics component store has only a limited number of IC's, I sometimes buy random IC's if they are compatible with Arduino and other microcontrollers.
And I also salvage old stuff. Here is a list of components I could use.

1. [MC1458](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/slos069c/slos069c.pdf) DUAL General-purpose operational amplifier
2. [TDA2822M](http://www.st.com/st-web-ui/static/active/en/resource/technical/document/datasheet/CD00000134.pdf) DUAL low-voltage power amplifier
3. [UA741CN](http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/datasheet/CD00001252.pdf) General-purpose single operational amplifier
4. [AD7395](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/307375.pdf) Dual, Serial-Input 12-/10-Bit DAC

As I have no oscilloscope and other professional stuff to measure electronic current, I hope you can show me how to **properly connect an audio signal to my microcontroller's ADC**.

Consider the fact that I know nothing. Complex explaination without a schematic wouldn't help to solve the problem for me and probably many other people.

The question:

**How to PROPERLY connect a standard headphone jack (mp3 player)/ audio out cable to a 0-5V Analog to digical converter Microcontroller's pin?**

Main problems:

1. With the tested online available circuits I get no readings from analog pin 0. 
   Analog pin 0 works perfectly (tested potentiometer only).
2. Now, I don't want to connect something to the MC's pins without knowing for sure that I output 0-5V at the correct amperage.

Extra:

1. I don't know why I always get reading 0 from Arduino even if I can hear the buzzer?
2. I never used a op-amp so I don't know what inverting input and non-inverting input is?
3. What does the C1 capacitor and why does it work if I invert the polarity?(buzzer)
4. Inverted audio cable pins also produce the same sound on a buzzer, why?
5. I'm testing on an Arduino micro but the final line in would be used on a Arduino micro, not sure if relevant.

**EDIT 1**

This uses the same op-amp I have

> Noise can be horrible !

https://bochovj.wordpress.com/2013/06/23/sound-analysis-in-arduino/
https://bochovj.files.wordpress.com/2013/06/circuitschematics.png

**EDIT 2**

Arduino Prescaler: up to 19kHz, not 17 what I have written in the comments.

http://apcmag.com/arduino-project-audio-spectrum-analyser.htm/

> But by knocking down the 128-prescaler to 32, we now increase the
>   sample rate by the same factor up to 38.4kHz. Thanks to Nyquist again,
>   that gives us an audio bandwidth of 19.2kHz, which is close enough to
>   20kHz-perfection.

EDIT 3

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fL23lX.png)</sup>

Comment: Are you aware of [MSGEQ7](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10468)? Would that be useful?

Comment: I think it would not work with my setup... the led grid already uses almost all pins. the msgeq7 needs more pins.. then i would need an external multiplexer ic... with FHT i only need one pin and have an array ready to use softwareside.. that allows me to display everything how i want.Also like i said my local electro supply is very limited...  i think they don't have an msgeq7....

Comment: Also at the end the FHT way is more precise than the MSGEQ7 as it allows up to 256 bands vs 7. All in one pin.

Comment: So, have you calculated how fast you need to sample your ADC to resolve all of the frequencies you want? What is the clock speed and the minimum ADC settling time? Does all of this support your requirements?

Comment: i read that the examples sample at 38khz and that would be up to 17khz in 256 bands. if it's that what you mean...but until i don't get a proper analogRead i can't go on.

Comment: but yeah ... on the arduino i already set the timer1 prescaler to 1 to achieve the flickerfree led's .... so i'm now not 100% shure if adding the FHT calculation to the code would slow down the led multiplexing...but that all comes later... now i need to get my arduino read the audio in signal properly

Comment: maybe the arduino micro is different than the arduino uno?... i'm testing on arduino micro... the final code will be put on an arduino uno.

Comment: It's the microprocessor that matters, not the development board. Check the specs for whatever Atmel chip the Uno uses and also check the crystal too. That should tell you how fast you can process. I very much suspect that FHT will introduce noticeable delay.

Comment: yeah i think both work... not at best but work. Uno works, micro>uno prolly also works... the processor is almost the same arduinos uses 8/16mhz crystals... uno&micro 16mhz... The problem is the circuit. No signal no testing.

Comment: In my example i need 8 bands with each 4 or more possible values... so not much. i can set the fht to 32 or prolly also at 16 or 8.... this should decrease the delay

Comment: but yeah ppl already tested with alot more bands leds and whatever on arduino and it works... so i don't think it's impossible. they all use a commercial led matrix... i wanna use my own.

Comment: it says the prescaler is set to 32.... atm my led multiplexing is set to 1... but i need to keep it at least at 8. that might be a problem if the fht is not able to work at a even higher frequency

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do what you are asking - it takes the audio in (AC-coupled) and amplifies it (inverted, but that won't matter) with a variable gain of up to about 5.5 (use R1 to adjust gain). It also centre-biases the signal around 2.5V (analogRead = 512 on the Arduino).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fG9UnR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

However, please do pay attention to the other comments on here regarding sampling rates and the amount of processing needed to be done to get the result you want. Also, don't swap out the opamp without some thought - that part is rail-to-rail input and output rated, which you will need in order to use the full input range of the Arduino's ADC.

Comment: My supply for shure does not have that opa344 ... can i do the same with the ic's i listed?UA741CN,MC1458??

Comment: Nope - you need an opamp with an output that can swing very near its voltage rails - known as a rail-to-rail output opamp (RRO or sometimes R/RO). None of the opamps you list is suitable. But the one I have suggested is available from CPC, Farnell, Mouser, Digikey, RS, is low cost and comes in a DIP package for easy prototyping.

Comment: And those resistor capacitor mix solution (where i posted the schematics)... why does that not work on my arduino micro?

Comment: The one schematic you have inline should have partially worked, although not with a full 0 to 5V swing as there is no gain (and in fact there is attenuation, which doesn't help). You should have read 512 (or thereabouts) pretty much all the time, with small variations up and down. You would have needed to make sure that the audio ground input was connected to the Arduino ground though - this is not very clear in your schematic.

Comment: i could not find a proper audio jack in,... anyway there is a line that starts from one of the audio inputs(-), passes trough some caps and resistors and goes into the arduino ground(GND).

Comment: You also need to connect the audio ground directly to the Arduino ground, otherwise the circuit has no input reference

Comment: the audio - is connected to the ground. the ground is the only thing that needs to be shared with all components... so yes. the gnd is connected. if you tell me where to find the triangles that represent ground i redraw the schematics... if you prefer triangles

Comment: added triangles

Comment: Excellent - well as I said, that should have given you readings around 512 but with no gain, so no full 0-5V swing.

Comment: readable ?? workable ... i mean would it be enough to get me tha bar graph light up ... in a non superprecise way? appar from that i get no 512 readings...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26965/discussion-between-stefandz-and-cocco).

Comment: ts942in would this one work? http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/389/stmicroelectronics_cd00002000-330369.pdf

Comment: It's a bit marginal - the input common-mode voltage range only extends up to 3.7V at 5V Vcc - and 2.5V + around 1V line peak = 3.5V, which is too close for my liking.

Comment: also in the opa344 is it a problem if it touches the 5,5volt on a microcontroller as they only allow max 5volt? -and about the ts942in if i add a 2nd power supply of 7-8 volt?

Comment: btw i already got it to working with the ic less version... range is very low.... noise touches up to 120of1024.. and the amount is only around 10-20... i already get a nice animation

Comment: I don't know where the 5.5V would be on your microcontroller - usually they run at 5V. Yes, the alternate part will work with a second power supply of 7-8V, but you will then need to limit the output to be a maximum of 5V in order to protect the micro. I really would recommend going with the opa344.

Comment: the opa goes up to 5.5v? i also have some professional dj equipement... and the heaphones output can go very high... and so i think maximizing the opa344 or whatever

Comment: How could it, if it is powered by 5V and is a linear device? The maximum output voltage cannot exceed the rail voltage for a normal opamp.

Comment: ah sure right... sorry. if i give the opa max 5v i get out max 5v